# Why is my data not showing in my GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a database where there is `userid`, `problemname` and `status` column. I am retrieving this data from database in an ArrayList and returning it. Now to show in GridView I have taken a DataTable and in the DataTable I have put three columns and I just want to show my data that is saved in the ArrayList in these columns by making one row.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList myArrayList = ConvertDataSetToArrayList();

    // Display each item of ArrayList
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("User Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Problem Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Status");

    foreach (Object row in myArrayList)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["User Id"] = ((DataRow)row)["userid"].ToString();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Problem Name"] = ((DataRow)row)   ["problemname"].ToString();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Status"] = ((DataRow)row)["status"].ToString();

    }

    GridView1.DataSource =dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

public ArrayList ConvertDataSetToArrayList()
{
    string con = " ";
    con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT userid,problemname,status FROM   problemtable", objsqlconn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
    foreach (DataRow dtRow in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        myArrayList.Add(dtRow);
    }
    objsqlconn.Close();
    return myArrayList;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="cdd">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Why is my data is not showing in my GridView?

Comment: Where do you assign a value from the DB to the check box?

Comment: Why do you need to use an array list? the gridview can bind direct to a datatable

Comment: `ArrayList` in 2014 ???

Comment: i want to add a checkbox in every row so that i can delete the row if the checkbox is selected..

Comment: What date? You are only selecting userid, problemname, status.  You have AutoGenerateColumns set to false, and only one checkbox column defined.  Set that to true to see all your data and then refine as needed.  Also, why are you using an array list?

Comment: so how will i retrieve my columns data from database..i want to retrieve data only from some column not all column from database...

Comment: Your sql statement determines your columns:
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT userid,problemname,status FROM   problemtable", objsqlconn);

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your data to specific controls in your gridview. For example, you need to have labels in your gridview itemtemplate to bind your data to. Here is an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="cdd">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Id">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_userid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("User Id") %>' CssClass="lbl"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Problem Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_problemname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Problem Name") %>' CssClass="lbl"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="status">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_status" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' CssClass="lbl"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that an `ArrayList` is a poor choice, but, regardless of how you're binding the data, you need to tell the gridview what it's supposed to show.  You can do this using inline tags or by using an `onitemdatabound` trigger.  I recommend you look up some more examples of gridviews.